# Unable to play wav file created by JFlac

Tags: java, audio, wav, bitrate, flac

I am creating java audio player. My target files are flac files which are converted into wav files by JFlac library. The problem i am getting is that program through me an exception when i try to play this song.
The exception is specifically:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No line matching interface SourceDataLine supporting format PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 24 bit, stereo, 6 bytes/frame, little-endian is supported.
```

But when i lower the quality of a song using vlc player like lowering its bitrate value i am able to play the song without any issue.
But i cannot play the original wav file.
Is there any way to lower the quality of wav file in java or anything else i can do to play the song.

This is where wav song is played:

```
public void playSound(String filename){

        String strFilename = filename;

        try {
            soundFile = new File(strFilename);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }

        try {
            audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }

        audioFormat = audioStream.getFormat();

        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, audioFormat);
        try {
//line where i am getting exception
                **sourceLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);**
                sourceLine.open(audioFormat);
        } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }

        sourceLine.start();

        int nBytesRead = 0;
        byte[] abData = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        while (nBytesRead != -1) {
            try {
                nBytesRead = audioStream.read(abData, 0, abData.length);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (nBytesRead >= 0) {
                @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                int nBytesWritten = sourceLine.write(abData, 0, nBytesRead);
            }
        }

        sourceLine.drain();
        sourceLine.close();
    }
```

Decoder function:

```
public void decode(String inFileName, String outFileName) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Decode [" + inFileName + "][" + outFileName + "]");
        FileInputStream is = null;
        FileOutputStream os = null;
        try {
            is = new FileInputStream(inFileName);
            os = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
            wav = new WavWriter(os);
            FLACDecoder decoder = new FLACDecoder(is);
            decoder.addPCMProcessor(this);
            decoder.decode();
        } finally {
            if (is != null) {
                is.close();
            }
            if (os != null) {
                os.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help plz.

Comment: Anybody there! Who can help me? Or any suggestion.